# mouseenter/mouseleave only working once

Tags: javascript

I made an image slider which images move from left to right, and I want to increase their size when the user mouses over them while decreasing their size when the mouse leaves. This works, but only one time. I think it may have something to do with how I declared the event listeners. Here is a working example: (http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/scrolling_Banner.html) and here is my code:

```
<script>
    var images = [];
    var imagePosition = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var cycle;
    var hoverImagePosition;

    window.onload = function scrolling() {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            images.push(document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i));
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
                document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).addEventListener("mouseenter", imageBigger);
                document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).addEventListener("mouseleave", imageSmaller);
            } else if (document.attachEvent) {
                // For IE 8 and earlier versions
                document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).attachEvent("mouseenter", imageBigger);
                document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).attachEvent("mouseleave", imageSmaller);
            }
        }
        cycle = setInterval(frame, 100);
    };

    function frame() {
        for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            if (imagePosition[x] == 100) {
                imagePosition[x] = 0;
            } else {
                imagePosition[x] = imagePosition[x] + 1;
                images[x].style.left = imagePosition[x] + '%';
            }
        }
    }

    function imageBigger() {
        clearInterval(cycle);
        this.style.zIndex = 1;
        this.style.width = 25 + "%";
        hoverImagePosition = parseInt(this.style.left) - 2.5;
        this.style.left = hoverImagePosition + "%";
    }

    function imageSmaller() {
        cycle = setInterval(frame, 100);
        this.style.zIndex = -1;
        this.style.width = 20 + "%";
        hoverImagePosition = parseInt(this.style.left) + 2.5;
        this.style.left = hoverImagePosition + "%";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use just a stylesheet?

Comment: Why another post of basically the same question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223122/javascript-mouseleave-event-not-working-when-elements-move-away-from-pointer

Comment: Nowhere near the same question. Same piece of code, different question. How is it remotely the same question? The other question had to do with images moving away from the mouse pointer yet still keeping the "mouseover" effect (which they should not since they moved away from the pointer) - I got rid of that problem by stopping the motion of the images entirely on "mouseover" and spawned this new problem. The old problem is still unsolved. pvg suggested using elementFromPoint(), but that does have good cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer has to do with you setting zIndex =-1 in imageSmaller. This likely puts the image behind the div/whatever and that's why it's not working again

Comment: Wow, it's usually some silly mistake like that after 8 hours of JS - thank you for pointing that out so quickly you saved me a headache!

Answer (score 2):

Change The `z-index` to 0 instead of -1

```js
        var images = [];
        var imagePosition = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        var cycle;
        var hoverImagePosition;
        
        window.onload = function scrolling() {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                images.push(document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i));
                if (document.addEventListener) {
                    // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
                    document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).addEventListener("mouseover", imageBigger);
                    document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).addEventListener("mouseout", imageSmaller);
                } else if (document.attachEvent) {
                    // For IE 8 and earlier versions
                    document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).attachEvent("mouseenter", imageBigger);
                    document.getElementById("scrollingImage" + i).attachEvent("mouseleave", imageSmaller);
                }
            }
            cycle = setInterval(frame, 100);
        };

        function frame() {
             for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                if (imagePosition[x] == 100) {
                    imagePosition[x] = 0;
                } else {                        
                    imagePosition[x] = imagePosition[x] + 1;
                    images[x].style.left = imagePosition[x] + '%';
                }
            }
        }
        
        function imageBigger() {
            clearInterval(cycle);
            this.style.zIndex = 1;
            this.style.width = 25 + "%";  
            hoverImagePosition = parseInt(this.style.left) - 2.5;
            this.style.left = hoverImagePosition + "%";
        }

        function imageSmaller() {
            cycle = setInterval(frame, 100);
            this.style.zIndex = 0;
            this.style.width = 20 + "%";    
            hoverImagePosition = parseInt(this.style.left) + 2.5;
            this.style.left = hoverImagePosition + "%";
        }
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/scrolling_Banner.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>BANNER</title>

<style>


</style></head>


<body>

    <p style="text-align:center; color:#d2d"><span>REAL TIME IS OSSIM</span></p>

    <div id="container">
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/red.jpg" id="scrollingImage0" style="left: 36%;">
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/orange.jpg" id="scrollingImage1" style="left: 36%;">
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/yellow.jpg" id="scrollingImage2" style="left: 36%;>
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/green.jpg" id="scrollingImage3" style="left: 36%;>
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/blue.jpg" id="scrollingImage4" style="left: 36%;>
        </a>


        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/red.jpg" id="scrollingImage5" style="left: 36%; >
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/orange.jpg" id="scrollingImage6" style="left: 36%;">
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/yellow.jpg" id="scrollingImage7" style="left: 36%;>
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/green.jpg" id="scrollingImage8" style="left: 36%;>
        </a>
        <a class="scrolling_Image" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <img src="http://www.public.asu.edu/~drwarner/imageslider/img/blue.jpg" id="scrollingImage9" style="left: 36%;">
        </a>
    </div>




</body></html>
```